# How to classify points in LAStools using shapefiles as reference

Tags: shapefile, lidar, classification, lastools

I am new to LAStools, and mostly use MicroStation/Terra for classifications, except MS is a resource heavy at times so can be slow and can crash. The macro we run uses shapefiles as a reference, and captures ground points along a 10m buffer of the shp file and then outputs it. Is it possible to do the same in LAStools? I was thinking to use lasclassify, importing the .las files, and then using bringing in the shapefiles as an overlay. But then I'm at a loss on whats next.'

Comment: Are you using lastools in the GUI or on the command line? This function takes all of the points that fall within one or multiple polygons and outputs them as a separate shapefile. is that what you want to do? https://lastools.github.io/download/lasclip_README.md

Comment: Hi there, yes I am using the GUI. It is sort of what I need, I think I can maybe try make this work. I need to capture ground points on an outside boundary, so maybe I can make a separate layer with the SHP file, make a buffer around those, export the buffer and use that for the clipping. Thanks so much for your reply

Comment: What type of scene are you looking at (urban, residential, grassland, forest etc.)?

Comment: Hi there, your solution to use lasclip has helped a lot. I am capturing water features such as lakes and streams, then need the nearby ground points to help elevate. I have just been making a buffer of the features and then using las clip to output the needed points,. This can be marked as SOLVED, thanks again